# How stretch div to fit contents until it reaches the height of its parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**EDIT: Sorry, I was unclear. I mean I want the outer div to stetch only until it hits the bottom of the window/parent and have that be the max.**

I want a parent div that stretches to fit its children but only until it reaches a max height. Solution *must* be cross browser but only needs to support Safari 7+, iOS Safari 7.1+, Chrome 30+, FF 35+, IE10+. So something like:

```
<!-- This would stretch to child's 200px height -->
<div class="outer">
    <div class="child">child</div>
</div>

<!-- This would stretch to until it reaches max height of 300px -->
<div class="outer">
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden; /* is this the best way? */
}

.child
{
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I'd prefer to do it only with CSS.

Comment: So, why you don't like `overflow: hidden;` in this solution? Do you have any restrictions? Do you need scroll-bar? If you need it, you can use `<iframe>`

Comment: Aren't you already doing what you want? Here it is using `overflow: scroll` http://jsfiddle.net/097rL3ys/

Comment: @dwreck08 `overflow: auto` is preferable to `scroll`, if you want the scrollbar to disappear when the height limit is not reached.

Comment: @Ori Drori, it wasn't a recommendation. It was an attempt to better understand the question.

Comment: @dwreck08 - I stand corrected :)

Comment: @AleshaOleg Sorry, I was unclear. I mean I want the outer div to stetch only until it hits the bottom of the window/parent and have that be the max. That's why my css was pseudo code

Comment: @DonRhummy so, you mean if you will have one `child` inside `outer` the height of `outer` should be 300px, because max-height is 300px, and if we have two `child` in `outer`. `Outer` should be 400px in height?

Comment: @AleshaOleg no, I mean if the `window` is 350px, and we have an `outer` with one `child` (200px), then the outer's `200px`, but if instead an `outer` has two `child`'s, then it's 350px max because its parent (the `window`) is only 350px.

Comment: @DonRhummy ahh, understood:) working on it

Comment: @DonRhummy so, do you mean [this](https://jsfiddle.net/udn3d1k1/)?

Comment: @AleshaOleg Sort of like that. I appreciate the help! The problem with your solution is that there's an endless number of screen heights. So it might be 360px tall or 410px, etc. It's dynamic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89531/discussion-between-aleshaoleg-and-don-rhummy).

Comment: @AleshaOleg ok. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: table` instead of `overflow` property.